# invalid reference format on building docker image on github actions

Tags: docker, github

i got this error on adding tag on my docker file

```
/usr/bin/docker buildx build --iidfile /tmp/docker-build-push-snALJd/iidfile --tag ***/image-micro-service:$(date +'%Y-%m-%d%H-%M-%S') --metadata-file /tmp/docker-build-push-snALJd/metadata-file .
ERROR: invalid tag "***/image-micro-service:$(date +'%Y-%m-%d%H-%M-%S')": invalid reference format
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: invalid tag "***/image-micro-service:$(date +'%Y-%m-%d%H-%M-%S')": invalid reference format
```

this is how i add tag:

```
 - name: Build Docker image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    push: false
    tags: ${{secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME}}/image-micro-service:$(date +'%Y-%m-%d%H-%M- 
    %S')
```

Comment: Are you sure that date function is supposed to execute?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just run arbitrary bash code in a GH actions instruction.

However, according to [build-push-action issues](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/33#issuecomment-1265891667), this could work:

```
...
      - name: Docker meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: name/app
          tags: |
            type=raw,value={{date 'Y-M-D-H-m-S'}}

      - name: Build Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          push: false
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
```

With this solution you use the docker metadata action to define the tags beforehand, and there you can use [`{{ date <'format'>}}`](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action?tab=readme-ov-file#date-format-tztimezone) expression.

#### Side note about date format

Your current `%Y-%m-%d%H-%M-%S`, or written like `Y-m-dH-M-S` in the momentjs format corresponds to `[year]-[minute]-[day of week][hour]-[month]-[fractional second]`. That's probably not what you want.